# How can I upload a SIM applet through OTA

Tags: gsm, javacard, apdu

I have created a simple Java Card applet for SIM, based on 2.2.2 version.
I try to upload to the SIM card using OTA, sms transport, but the SIM cards respond with different type errors, like "Insufficient security level" for eSIM, and "Instruction code not programmed or invalid (procedure byte), (ISO 7816-3)" for a SIM card.
The APDU command is "0x80 0xB0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x7F;", as I understand this command is related to the installer applet; this is the first command in the converted apdu script.

Comment: There seems to be a 0x00 too many in the command. Are you sure that this is what was sent? Did you generate the APDU or some library? Also, normally you receive a 16 bit / two byte status word, not a string, the string must be generated by some lib?

Comment: yes, I have generated APDU script from Java Card Kit, using scriptgen utility. I think for upload I have to use Global Platform standard